# error setting up LDAPS with AWS Managed AD - unable to download

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, ssl, ldap, aws-directory-services

I am trying to setup LDAPS with AWS Managed AD but am receiving an "unable to download" error when opening PKIVIEW. See screenshots below.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I granted Public Access to the bucket and folders but the URL would take me to S3 bucket properties tab for the bucket if logged in otherwise would take to me to an AWS login prompt.

I have reached step number 10 under "Step 4b: Configure Enterprise Subordinate CA" on the document listed on the AWS site in trying to setup LDAPS using AWS Managed AD. See link below.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-enable-ldaps-for-your-aws-microsoft-ad-directory/

This is the last action before Step 5.

For the record, I have set up exactly per instructions in this document. Both the RootCA and SubordinateCA have joined the domain and are in the same security group and subnet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

PS. I have also posted this question on the AWS forum

Comment: the event viewer is reporting error ID 44 "The "Windows default" Policy Module "Initialize" method returned an error. Cannot find object or property. The returned status code is 0x80092004 (-2146885628).  The Active Directory Certificate Services Policy contains no valid Certificate Templates.
" error in the event log with ID 44. I have just attached an image in the initial post.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this issue with a combination of two things

1. removed/reinstalled the cert services (so started from step 3 in the doc again) and this time around did not join the rootca to the domain - I misread this the first time around
2. changed the S3 URL paths to align with how they are noted in the doc (because there are a couple of difft ways in pathing the S3 URL). I then tested that I could browse and download each of the files using the S3 URL without logging into AWS and this worked.